# How to calculate number of days between two dates in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to subtract two dates in R. These are the two dates via the structure command:

```
str(standard_data_4testing$start_datetime)
 POSIXct[1:489124], format: "2016-02-01 00:38:49" "2016-02-01 07:48:53" "2016-02-01 08:32:08" "2016-02-01 11:21:13" ...

str(standard_data_4testing$original_installdate)
 Date[1:489124], format: "2015-10-15" "2015-10-15" "2015-10-15" "2016-01-29" "2016-01-29" "2016-01-29" ...
```

I created both with `as.Date` functions in R but `start_datetime` has date and time and `original_installdate` only has date in the original data as reflected above.

Is there a way to subtract them?

I tried to subtract using this statement:

```
standard_data_4testing$start_datetime - standard_data_4testing$original_installdate
```

but I get this error:

> Warning message: Incompatible methods ("-.POSIXt", "-.Date") for "-"

after it prints out some data:

> [6049] "2016-02-01 09:48:44 UTC" "2016-02-01 07:24:08 UTC" "2016-02-01
> 09:02:33 UTC" "2016-02-01 09:14:29 UTC"  [6053] "2016-02-01 10:49:46
> UTC" "2016-02-01 19:07:52 UTC" "2016-02-01 02:39:04 UTC" "2016-02-01
> 03:59:29 UTC"  [6057] "2016-02-01 07:13:05 UTC" "2016-02-01 07:58:50
> UTC" NA

I've also tried using POSIXct but received a similar error.

Is there any way I can subtract the two dates, despite the differences in their components?

Comment: Can the time component in the first format be neglected?

Comment: message says one of them is` POSIxt` and the other `Date`.  If they are the same class, you can subtract.

Comment: DatamineR - that is an interesting idea. I will try to remove it as I define it .asDate and see if that helps. I tried that and received the same error still: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("-.POSIXt", "-.Date") for "-"

Comment: @Jazzmine: don't use str, use dput to give us a reproducible example

Comment: Anyway, you can use `difftime` function `difference <- difftime(dates1,dates2,units='days')`, and get a numeric using `as.numeric(difference)` (N.B. `difftime` it automatically converts Date's to POSIXct)

Comment: Thanks digEmAll. I'm testing difftime. I wasn't familiar with it. I got very big numbers with it, so I am going to specify units=days to see if that helps. If not, I'll send dput results.

Comment: Thanks digEmAll. This worked great when I specified unit=days as shown here: units=c("days") as I wanted days in for my output. Thanks for sharing as I wasn't aware of this function.

Answer (score 14):

Convert both dates to the `POSIXct` class first. Be sure to do the calculations in the same timezone, the POSIXt classes default to your locale timezone, `as.Date` does not use a timezone when converting from character to Date.

```
test1 <- as.Date("2016-01-01")
test2 <- strptime("2016-01-02", format="%Y-%m-%d", tz="UTC")
difftime(as.POSIXct(test2), as.POSIXct(test1, tz="UTC"), units="days")
# Time difference of 1 days
```

When converting Dates from `POSIXct` to `Date` always give the timezone as an argument explicitly, since `as.Date.POSIXct` seems to ignore the timezone from the `POSIXct` object, as you see in this example (this might be platform dependent):

```
x <- as.POSIXct("2020-02-22 00:05", tz="CET")
as.Date(x)
as.Date(x, tz="UTC")
as.Date(x, tz="CET")
```

Comment: `as.Date.character` has no `tz` argument, that value is completely ignored. I'm not sure I would say `as.Date` defaults to UTC, but rather that `Date` class in R is completely ignorant of time zones.

Comment: Thank you, I added some info on the `tz` argument.